# Using mysql Regexp in a select statement not the where clause

Tags: mysql

So what i want to do is use a Regex to select only certain parts of data from a column

Example :

SELECT URL REGEXP 'http://' from websitelist --(website list is a list of URL's)

If I run that against the table it returns 1 foreach row in which 'htt://' was found, what I want is to return the string that matches the regexp

Comment: There is no way to do this in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `REGEXP` operator performs a match and returns `0` or `1` based on whether the string matched the expression or not.  It does not provide a way to extract the matched portion.  I don't think that there is any way to extract the matched portion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use just use string functions if it's as simple as your example - just removing http://

```
SELECT REPLACE(URL, 'http://', '') AS url FROM websitelist;
```

Probably faster as there is overhead for the REGEX engine.

Comment: I dont want to replace text , rather just return text that matches the regexp I pass in

Comment: Just to be clear, this only replaces it for your `SELECT`. It doesn't actually update the field. So you want to return http://?

Comment: I got the part about it not updating the data, Yes i only want to return what text would match my regexp , in this case the 'http://' , but it could be anything

Comment: As **D.Shawley** said, the `REGEXP` functions only return true or false. Not the match. You would need to build this into the query yourself: `IF(URL REGEXP 'http://', 'http://', '')` or just alias the field and interpret it in your results: `URL REGEXP 'http://' AS has_http`. If you have many matches, I suggest doing this with a different technology.

Comment: It seems like I am going to have to do it code side , was hoping to minimize processing but its fine